# Dynamically populate dropdown - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown in angularJS defined as:

```
$scope.Ids = [ {
                id : 'ID-100',
                name : 'ID-100'
            }, {
                id : 'ID-200',
                name : 'ID-200'
            }, {
                id : 'ID-300',
                name : 'ID-300'
            } ];
$scope.Id = $scope.Ids[0];

<select class="custom-select" ng-model="Id" ng-options="choice.name for choice in Ids"></select>
```

My requirement is to dynamically populate these Ids from DB.

I have a spring controller that makes a call to DB:

```
$http({
                        'url' : '/getIds',
                        'method' : 'POST',
                        'headers' : {
                            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                        },
                        'params' : data
                    }).then(function(response) {
                        $scope.Ids = response.data.Ids;
                    });
```

and yields a list:

```
["ID-100", "ID-200", "ID-300"]
0: "ID-100"
1: "ID-200"
2: "ID-300"
```

My $scope.Ids will now be having the new list. I need to map this list to my `$scope.Ids` in dropdown format and make my dropdown display the first record.

Can someone give an idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is already correct, however your approach should be like below.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);

app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    
$scope.Ids = [{
                id : 'ID-100',
                name : 'ID-100'
            }, {
                id : 'ID-200',
                name : 'ID-200'
            }, {
                id : 'ID-300',
                name : 'ID-300'
            }];
            
$scope.Id = $scope.Ids[0];
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="MainViewController.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="dobController">
  <select class="custom-select" ng-model="Id" ng-options="choice.name for choice in Ids"></select>
  <div>
    <h1> Selected one is : {{Id}} </h1>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sajeetharan, please find the updated question. I have added the spring controller calling section. I am receiving an error  "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" when I'm trying $scope.Id.id

Comment: @Mike sounds like you are trying to use wrong property. When you are setting your $scope.Ids from your http request, $scope.Ids = response.data.Ids, it is setting the Ids to what you get from your database, and your database response does not have id property in it. In this case, since your response is array of string, not objects, you will have trouble viewing the dropdown options as well with the given solution by Sajeetharan.

Comment: Yes Caner. That was what I need. I need on how to change that to get a dropdown just like a default dropdown.