# How to remove and add dropdown values based on the condition selected by another dropdown in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

My requirement:
I have to create a form row that has two select dropdowns and add and delete button at last
1. the first dropdown will have a list of values for ed.. ['one', 'two', 'three','four']
2. the second dropdown will have the condition ['and','or']

let say the first row of the form value selected like ['one'] ['and'] then clicking on the add button then the second row will create. here first dropdown should not show the 'one' value because the condition is 'and'. if user select or then it should all the values. similary for all the rows i have to create logic in angular.

HTML Code:

```html
<div class="state-filter-conditions-grid subs-model-sec filter-grid" *ngFor="let filterCondition of filters;  index as i">
  <!-- OUTPUT PROPERTY -->

    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="filterView == 'subscription'? attrs: map; context: { index: i }"></ng-container>


  <!-- CONNECTOR CONDITION -->
  <div class="dt-attr valueCondition ctrl-condition minimal">
    <div class="abs-cheveron select-box-cheveron">
      <select class="state-select" [(ngModel)]="filters[i].op">
        <option *ngFor="let val of op" [value]="val">{{val}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- INPUT -->
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="filterView != 'subscription'? attrs: map; context: { index: i }"></ng-container>
  <!-- SELECT -->
  <div class="dt-attr icons center-align">
    <select class="ctrl-condition" *ngIf="!(i==filters.length-1)" [(ngModel)]="filters[i].logop" (change)="operatorChange(filters[i])">
      <option *ngFor="let val of logop" [value]="val">{{val}}</option>
    </select>

  </div>
  <!-- ICONS -->

  <div class="dt-attr icons center-align">
    <button *ngIf="i==filters.length-1" class="add-btn" (click)="addStateConditionRow()"><i
        class="fa fa-sm fa-plus add-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    <button *ngIf="i>0" class="delete-btn" (click)="deleteStateConditionRow(i)"><i
        class="fa fa-sm fa-trash delete-icon"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template  #attrs let-i="index">
  <div class="dt-attr ">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!dataProps">
      <input class="ctrl-attr" type="text" [(ngModel)]="filters[i].value">
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="dataProps">
      <select class="value-select" [(ngModel)]="filters[i].value">
        <option *ngFor="let data of dataProps" [value]="data.attrId">{{data.attrName}}</option>
      </select>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template  #map let-i="index">
  <div class="dt-attr ctrl-condition minimal">
    <input class="ctrl-attr" type="text" clickOutside (clickOutside)="closeAccordion($event)" (click)="openAccordion($event)" [(ngModel)]="filters[i].attribute">
    <div *ngIf="showAccordion" class="state-filter-accordion" style="position: absolute;
    top: 105%;
    width: 100%;z-index:1">
      <app-common-accordion-mapping [filterInputRef]="filterInputRef" [inputAttributes]='inputAttributes' ></app-common-accordion-mapping>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

can you guys help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This website is to ask help with a code, not someone code for you...show what you got so far, maybe someone will point you in the right direction...

Comment: Can you please set up a snippet or a stackblitz/codepen/jsfiddle.. something testable? Without seeing your data sources and an example it's impossible to help - not to mention your actual question is difficult to understand. It would be easier if htere was an example and we could see the data, html, ts etc. Thanks

Comment: @bagya, you can use `<ng-container *ngFor="let val of op"><option *ngIf="<replace by your condition>">..</option></ng-container>` You need find the "condition" to show the option or not. Remember that as you're using ngModel, so you can use the variables to create the condition

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to dynamically populate dropdown based on a particular logic. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151646/dynamically-populate-dropdown-angularjs) stackoverflow answer covers that for AngularJS and  [a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60036257/how-to-change-dynamically-dropdown-values-in-angular-8) + [blog](https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-select-with-angular-forms) for Angular 8 . However I cannot help you with the business logic itself as it is not clear to me.

Comment: The linked answer is for AngularJS while this question is for Angular 2.0 or greater.

Comment: @MikkelChristensen Thanks for pointing out, I updated my answer with an example for Angular 8